# how to add incremental counter in groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 product_id      description
 1               abc
 2               def
 3               fer
 4               tyu
 5               abc
 6               def
```

What I want to do is assign incremental number to unique descriptions groups. My desired dataframe is as follows

```
 product_id      description    item_id
 1               abc            1 
 2               def            2
 3               fer            3
 4               tyu            4
 5               abc            1
 6               def            2
```

I am doing following thing in pandas

```
 group_vars = ['description']
 data = data.merge(data.drop_duplicates(group_vars).reset_index(drop=True), on=group_vars)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need [`series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html) here:

```
df['item id']=df['description'].factorize()[0]+1
print(df)
```

---

```
   product_id description  item id
0           1         abc        1
1           2         def        2
2           3         fer        3
3           4         tyu        4
4           5         abc        1
5           6         def        2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `factorize` answer is great, but you could also use `map`:

Create the series that maps description to item id:

```
l = data.drop_duplicates('description').set_index('description').product_id
```

Which gives:

```
print(l)
description
abc    1
def    2
fer    3
tyu    4
```

Now create your new column by mapping `l` to `description`:

```
data['group_id'] = data.description.map(l)
```

---

```
   product_id description  group_id
0           1         abc         1
1           2         def         2
2           3         fer         3
3           4         tyu         4
4           5         abc         1
5           6         def         2
```